# How to set up a mobile testing lab for physical parallel execution on Android phones

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile-automation, test-strategy

I need to set up a physical mobile testing lab mainly for `Android devices`.

I have to run test on `100 Android devices` in `parallel`, I will be using `Appium` with `TestNG` framework.

Please someone guide me how to design the mobile lab setup.

What tools and resources I will need, like strong `USB hubs` recommend some if any, or any workstation or HUB required to run or my `Windows machine` can also run the test?

Answer (score 1):

Just add your [Appium Nodes to Selenium Grid](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/grid/).

```
> appium --nodeconfig /path/to/nodeconfig.json
# or, if running from source:
> node . --nodeconfig /path/to/nodeconfig.json
```

The grid will select the available device matching the given desired capabilities.

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "<e.g._iPhone5_or_iPad4>",
          "version":"<version_of_iOS_e.g._7.1>",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "platform":"<platform_e.g._MAC_or_ANDROID>"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://<host_name_appium_server_or_ip-address_appium_server>:<appium_port>/wd/hub",
    "host": "<host_name_appium_server_or_ip-address_appium_server>",
    "port": <appium_port>,
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": <grid_port>,
    "hubHost": "<Grid_host_name_or_grid_ip-address>"
    "hubProtocol": "<Protocol_of_Grid_defaults_to_http>"
  }
}
```

Comment: I also found this [blog post](https://appiumpro.com/editions/54-using-appium-with-selenium-grid) mentioning the 100 nodes scenario.